# Ubuntu 19-10 Gnome Doesn't Come up

Tags: networking, gnome, 19.10

I have been running Ubuntu 19-10 for a couple of months on a new Dell Optiplex 9020.  Yesterday after applying a routine update to the software GNOME failed to complete startup, so I am left looking at the screen with the blinking lights that imitate the main display of the original Starship Enterprise.  I can only run the system from the Ubuntu USB.  I cannot see anything in the logs to explain why GNOME is not running.  That means I can see everything on the system but I cannot execute any commands from within the system. What should I do? I could undoubtedly login from another system on the same network but I do not know what IP address has been assigned.

Comment: _ip -a_ will show you the IP address of that machine.  But, what happens when you run _startx_ ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show me a screenshot or cell phone picture of what you're seeing? Are you seeing blinking lights at the "Ubuntu" startup screen, or after you log in?

Comment: heynnema: I cannot log in because the logon screen is itself displayed by Gnome. All I am seeing is the blinking lights of the screen that is displayed instead of the console log.

Comment: K7AAY: What do you mean "what happens when you run startx".  I am not given the opportunity to run any commands.

Comment: I have the boot mode set to BIOS so I have tried booting while holding down the shift key, but I never see the GRUB menu.  Very strange result: If i repeatedly hit the ESC key while powering up the system does complete initialization, but again I never see the GRUB menu.